Ruby Gosu: Is there any method to use multiple windows with ruby gosu?
Is there any way to implement window states using gosu? I am making a game with ruby gosu and I want to have a main-menu screen and option screen before entering into the actual game. I have my game screen already implemented. How can I call different windows back and forth in ruby? I already search on the web and I can't find any helpful sources, so I am asking here. If there is any page I can check, the link to the source would be fine.Thanks

You are supposed to add the drawing logic yourself, including any screen/state handling.
